# How to move focus to next control in Avalonia

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, avaloniaui

What's the equivalent of this line in Avalonia?

```
control.MoveFocus(new TraversalRequest(FocusNavigationDirection.Next));
```

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me:

```
var next = KeyboardNavigationHandler.GetNext(control, NavigationDirection.Next);
if (next != null)
{
    FocusManager.Instance?.Focus(next, NavigationMethod.Directional);
}
```

Source: https://github.com/AvaloniaUI/Avalonia/discussions/7603